# Javac -encoding options

Tags: java, character-encoding, javac

Where can I find a complete listing of all the character encodings supported by the `javac` command?

I have found suggestions of how to specify the encoding that a file uses with the `-encoding` flag in other answers, which contain several useful examples of supported encodings encountered commonly in the wild. I think it would also be useful if an exhaustive list was documented somewhere, and I have not found one.

Perhaps it depends on the version of `javac`? Perhaps also it coincides completely with the number of encodings that the java standard library has support for? I suppose the first step is to generate a list of encodings which are supported by the library, [which has been done](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Java-charset-Supported-Character-Encodings-in-JDK.html), but even if this is done it's not completely clear we'd be left with an *exhaustive* list.

Answer (score 0):

Each J2SE version will list its supported encoding sets. For example, this show the [encoding sets supported by Java SE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

`javac` is the compiler, encoding sets doesn't depend upon compiler version but each release will list its supported encoding sets.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I know that `javac` is the compiler. Thanks.

I'm asking a few slightly more subtle questions: 1) whether anyone has verified that the `javac -encoding <encoding>` option supports each of the encodings in those lists (which should be easy to check using a script, if you have a lot of examples of java source encoded in several different ways), and 2) whether there's any way of verifying that `javac` does not support any other encodings.

Answer (score 0):

The link above gives the required minimum: "The java.io.InputStreamReader, java.io.OutputStreamWriter, java.lang.String classes, and classes in the java.nio.charset package can convert between Unicode and a number of other character encodings. The supported encodings vary between different implementations of the Java Platform, Standard Edition 7 (Java SE 7). The class description for java.nio.charset.Charset lists the encodings that any implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition 7 is **required** to support."

See [availableCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets()) which gives the collection of all character encodings **actually supported** by the implementation you happen to be using.